# jQuery UI datepicker - add static text underneath the calendar?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

This is on the one that pops up when you click the linked input element. I want to be able to insert some static text underneath the table of dates that will appear and stay even if the user scrolls to different months.

I managed to sort of getting working by, with jQuery, using

```
$('.ui-datepicker').after('text');
```

On the `.ui-datepicker` class. The problem with that was, it didn't work when the user scrolled to the next month. I managed to fix that as well, by constantly clearing and re-adding the text with `setTimeout`. That was really hacky, but worked.

The next problem came when I had multiple calendars on the page, each with different texts. I tried targeting specific instances on `.ui-datepicker` with the above method, but I discovered there is actually only one instance of the datepicker that is shared between all calendar fields on the page.

So is it actually possible?

Answer (score 1):

One solution for presenting different texts on multiple datepickers on the same page is to create data holders next to the id/class space of each datepicker location. Then load the data content for the datepicker selected using (this).

**Example html code:**
The data holder contains the specific text to be displayed for the associated datepicker like so:

```
<p>Date1: <input type="text" class="datepicker" 
           data-dptxt="the text1 to display in datepicker" ></p>

<p>Date2: <input type="text" class="datepicker" 
           data-dptxt="the Second text to display" ></p>
```

**Example jQuery code:**
Then the jQuery text injection into the selected datepicker calendar would be something like this:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker()
    .on( "click", function() {
        var dTxt = $( this ).data('dptxt');
    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').after('<span class="middle">'+dTxt+'</>');
});
```

I've added a little CSS formatting so that you can easily see the additional semi-dynamic text changing between the two datepickers.

See my working **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xodt5sh5/)** solution in action (images below from the jsFiddle link :)

[image]
<sub>(source: [web-asylum.com](http://web-asylum.com/help-images/datepicker-extra-text-jquery0.jpg))</sub>
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need create a variable to hold the instance of the datepicker.  So When you create it, do this:

```
var myDatePicker = $("#myDatePickerElement").datepicker();
myDatePicker.after("text");
```

Comment: But I don't create it, jquery ui does, behind the scenes. And even when you have multiple ones on the page, they all use the same instance.

Comment: When you use the variable to cache the current instance of a jQuery UI element, you are accessing ONLY that element.  So by selecting myDatePicker, you are only accessing that instance.

Answer (score 0):

To get around your "hacky" `setTimeout` workaround, you can attach `click` event handlers to the prev and next buttons.  Here's code adapted from [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26532357/3120446).

```js
$(function() {
    function appendText(text) {
        $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').after('<span class="middle">'+lastText+'</>');
    }

    function addClickHandlers() {
        $('.ui-datepicker-prev, .ui-datepicker-next')
            .on('click', function() {
                addClickHandlers();
                appendText();
            });
    }

    var lastText;
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker()
        .on( "click", function() {
            lastText = $( this ).data('dptxt');
            appendText();
            addClickHandlers();
        });
});
```