# Jquery datepicker - cannot tab from text input to datepicker input

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have several form fields (all text inputs besides 1 jquery datepicker input). The first field is a normal text input field. The second input is the datepicker. Inputs 3 through 8 are all regular text inputs. When I place the cursor in the first text input field and enter some text then I tab to get into the datepicker field, nothing happens. The cursor remains in the first text field and will not enter the datepicker field. If I place the cursor inside the datepicker field, the calendar popup displays and I am able to tab out of the field to the next text input ... and I can tab all the way through all the remaining text input fields.

Searching Google doesn't give many ideas or possible solutions.

Comment: I just looked at the datepicker demo and you definatley can tab to it.  Can you create a jsfiddle with your code so we can see?

Comment: I will attempt to add my code. It's a .NET app that uses:jquery-1.7.2.js and jquery.ui.datepicker-en.js

Answer (score 0):

A sure way of being able to tab through all html input fields is to use the tabindex element.
In HTML 4.01, the tabindex attribute can be used with: , , , , , , and 
In HTML 5 all input elements accept it.

Example =

```
<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/" tabindex="2">W3Schools</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com/" tabindex="1">Google</a>
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com/" tabindex="3">Microsoft</a>
```

Whichever input has the datepicker doesn't matter as long as the tabindex numbers follow in order.

datepicker code shown in the stack thread **[jQuery UI datepicker - add static text underneath the calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054854/jquery-ui-datepicker-add-static-text-underneath-the-calendar)** also has a jsFiddle which tabs between inputs fine. Check your code against this example to see if you have something different.