# How to add some text to jquery datepicker popup calendar

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have 3 datepicker fields in a form, and on one of them, I have minDate set to 4.

I would like to add some text (under or next to) that calendar popup only, explaining why this is necessary to the user.

I don't wish to alter the look of the form itself (this is an 'after all the work is already completed' customer requested change.) So simply adding the text to the form isn't an option as it will completely destroy the spacing.

To summarize: I simply would like to add a couple of lines of text explaining to the user why they can't pick these dates - right on the popup calendar - for that field only.

Is this possible, or do I need to use another solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative solution which I go into detail at this stackoverflow thread:
[jQuery UI datepicker - add static text underneath the calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054854/jquery-ui-datepicker-add-static-text-underneath-the-calendar)

Essentially you can use jQuery to identify just one datepicker or you can show different texts on multiple datepickers on the same page. The method is to create data holders next to the id/class space of each datepicker location. Then load the data content for the datepicker selected using (this).

**Example jQuery code:** Then the jQuery text injection into the selected datepicker calendar would be something like this:

```
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker().on( "click", function() {
    var dTxt = $( this ).data('dptxt');
    $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').after('<span class="middle">'+dTxt+'</>');
});
```

This neatly inserts any message you desire inside the bottom of the calendar display.

of course, the data element contains the message for the specific datepicker like this:

```
<p>Date1: <input type="text" class="datepicker" 
       data-dptxt="the text1 to display in datepicker" ></p>
```

See the other thread for a working jsFiddle example:
[jQuery UI datepicker - add static text underneath the calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054854/jquery-ui-datepicker-add-static-text-underneath-the-calendar)

Comment: This works but the appended content disappears when the user changes the month.

Answer (score 0):

you could append some div containing note using [beforeShow](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShow) function, like:

```
$(".some_element").datepicker({
    ....
    beforeshow: function(inp, inst) {
        //call the function to append div to datepicker
        appendNoteDiv();
    }
});

function appendNoteDiv() {
    var parElem = $("#ui-datepicker-div");
    //check if your div exists, append if not
    if( !parElem.find(".note_div").length ) {
        parElem.append("<div class='note_div'>Your Content here</div>");
    }
}
```