# text underneath date in Jquery ui datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

How could i get underneath the date a text, example premium or standard in jquery ui [date picker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

[image]

Comment: personally I think you would need to modify the plugin source to do it if calculations based on dates need to be made. Otherwise might be able to do it using css `:after`

Comment: date text will be dynamic based on month and your text also looks dynamic . it will change based on the month and date . so you may not define array and do . but i think you can find each column with class and based on its value you can replace the text !!!<td data-year="2014" data-month="8" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay" class=" "><a href="#" class="ui-state-default">16</a></td>

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a screenshot of `.datepicker()`, it looks like a fullCalendar plugin. The calendar that is brought up by jQuery-UI is far too small to append text to.

Comment: To answer your deleted question from just now; you can pass `this` to `.forEach()` as the second argument, i.e. `ourdates.forEach(function(entry) { ... }, this);`

Comment: Hi Ali, have you solved this?  If not, please share with me how you decide which is Premium delivery and which is Standard, and I shall be able to provide you with a separate jQuery function which would add the text below the day numbers.
Css styling will control the size of the datepicker.

Comment: Take a look at stack thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054854/jquery-ui-datepicker-add-static-text-underneath-the-calendar  for possible clue to how to inject suitable text under dates.